# Copy rows depending on cell value from different workbooks in multiple folders

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automate a process. I have multiple workbooks in different subfolders locally. I want to import all rows with a specific cell value to the MasterWorkbook.
How can I do that?

Comment: Don't ask us to solve a whole project, that is a way too broad to answer. Go small steps and try to solve them one by one doing a decent research on each step. If you get stuck in a step ask only about this one step. • Research how to loop through workbooks in a folder. Research how to filter your data in a workbook and finally research how to copy filtered data only. Then come back with your attempt and ask a question to it.

Comment: Question is too broad but you should probably begin with a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some of the code that you've already done so you can be assisted better? the logic you would employ in your code would be:

1. Loop through all files in a folder and subfolders

   **In the loop, do the following for each file**
2. Open file
3. Loop through the column that contains the cell value you want to check
4. If the check is true then copy the row to the main file
5. close file

And this process will continue until all files have been checked. All the above type of code can be easily googled or found on this site. You might want to also look at finding the lastrow for each file that you open to make the code dynamic.